# How can I call multiple asynchronous depended functions asynchronously for each iteration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I have some functions,

```
const firstResult = await firstFunction(parameters)
const secondResult = await secondFunction(firstResult)
const finalResult = await finalFunction(secondResult)
```

They're asynchronous functions, returning some promise. Now there's a scenario like I have an array of parameters that is getting passed to `firstFunction at each iteration and it should follow the same flow of execution. Something like this:

```
const results = arrayOfParamters.map(async parameter => {
    const firstResult = await firstFunction(parameters)
    const secondResult = await secondFunction(firstResult)
    const finalResult = await finalFunction(secondResult)
    return finalResult
})
```

So how can I achieve this more efficiently? One of the efficient solutions that I can visualize is to execute `firstFunction` for the first `parameter`, start executing `secondFunction` and till then the promise for `secondFunction` is fulfilled, start executing the `firstFunction` for the next iteration of `arrayOfParameters`. Is there any way I can achieve this? Seems like `Promise.all` will not be worth it if the whole loop is going to be executed synchronously.

Comment: Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: What evidence do you have that the current code is inefficient? Are you seeing slowness? This seems like premature optimization to me.

Comment: @ZloiGoroh yep got it. allSettled suits more in my usecase. thanks!

Comment: @HereticMonkey It is premature optimization. I was curious is there any way we can optimize any further. sorry bout that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is already set up to do that.

It's going to start by running the map code for element 0 of the array. It synchronously calls `firstFunction` but then it hits an `await`, and so the mapping function returns a promise. This promise gets put in element 0 of `results`. Then it does the same thing for element 1, then 2, etc. So it will call `firstFunction` for every element of the array, and assign an array of promises to `results`, but none of them will block or wait.

The array of promises has now been created, so the code continues on to whatever comes after this line. Over time, the calls to `firstFunction` will start finishing, and the `async` functions will resume, calling `secondFunction` for each element of the array (not necessarily in exactly the same order, since this is happening at an unpredictable time). And then eventually they'll all do third function, and finally they'll resolve their promises to `finalResult`.

So the only thing missing from your code is to know when it's all done, and for that you need `Promise.all`:

```
const promises = arrayOfParamters.map(async parameter => {
    const firstResult = await firstFunction(parameter)
    const secondResult = await secondFunction(firstResult)
    const finalResult = await finalFunction(secondResult)
    return finalResult
})

const results = await Promise.all(promises)
```

Comment: Makes sense, so I was wrong if it can be optimized further.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Promise.then` chain the result as a parameter to the next function you can use that instead of `async` `await`

You can use `Promise.all` like this:

```
const promiseChain = arrayOfParamters.map((parameter) => firstFunction(parameter).then(secondFunction).then(finalFunction));
const results = await Promise.all(promiseChain);
```